# When/how did Harry Truman give the order to bomb Hiroshima?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, japan

Am I correct in assuming that Truman and only Truman had the authority to order the bombing of Hiroshima? After all, it was the very first A-bomb and procedures may not have been formalized yet. It occurs to me that maybe a theater commander like Gen. MacArthur could have given the order.

Given that Truman was at Potsdam when he made the decision to bomb Hiroshima, did he have a secure method of communications to use to communicate his order from Potsdam? If so, what was that method? When was that order actually given? I'm guessing it was at least several days before the bombing since someone had to order the bomb moved to Tinian and a plane and flight crew chosen and assembled at Tinian.

Could Truman have aborted if he'd changed his mind? How late could he have successfully aborted? Right up until the bombardier pressed the "Bombs Away" button? Or would it have been early, say up until the moment Enola Gay left Tinian, after which it might have been running silent?

I realize this is all academic now but it's not impossible to imagine Truman having a change of heart and deciding not to bomb Hiroshima. Let's say the Japanese surrendered on August 4 because they could see that the war was lost. I'm curious how late he could abort the bombing if he'd really wanted to.

Comment: Thank you all! Each of your answers answered part of my question. Can I put a check mark beside all of the answers? Or am I limited to just one? I just answered my own question: I checked the first, then the second, after which the first one had been un-checked. I'll choose the first one but value EACH of the answers!

Comment: The Japanese military junta knew damn well the war was lost. The reason they were still insisting on fighting on was because they were betting that if they made a land invasion of Japan too costly in terms of lives - Japanese as well as Allied - the Allies would sue for peace on terms that would let the junta escape justice for the atrocities committed on the chinese mainland.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Truman retained *mission authorization* within  the Oval Office, but all further details were delegated through the normal chain of command to [Colonel Tibbets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Tibbets) to plan the mission.

Once the Japanese response to the [Potsdam declaration](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Potsdam-Declaration), *Mokusatsu*, had been sent and received, it would have been tacitly understood all around that  any further decisions could only be implemented on a *best efforts* basis. Mission authorization was given and Tibbets arranges a suitable date according to weather forecasts.

Aboard the [Enola Gay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enola_Gay#Hiroshima_mission) the bomb was armed after take off and its safety devices removed about 30 minutes before it was dropped. Conceivably that latter process could be reversed, but I am unsure that it would have been attempted. The bomb could always have been dropped at sea for disposal, though [General Grove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_Groves)s would likely have been most disappointed at that result.

Note that any last minute communication from the Japanese would have been received with extreme skepticism, as merely a delaying tactic. It is unlikely to my mind that any such would have had the slightest bearing on the Hiroshima mission.

The key point here is that there were no special go/no-go arrangements for the mission. Once authorized it was expected to take place at the earliest suitable opportunity. No arrangement for recall subsequent to launch was planned for because any abort decision was up to the commander of the mission, Colonel Tibbets.

Answer (score 30):

I came across [a document](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/bomb/large/documents/index.php?documentdate=1945-07-30&documentid=5&pagenumber=1) in the [Truman library](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/bomb/large/index.php) while researching another question here, which according to the [one Library page](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/hst/d.htm), seems to be the closest thing to documenting the order by Truman authorizing the bomb drop:

First is the request for authorization, dated 31 July, 1945:
[image]

> FROM: AGWAR Washington
> TO: Tripartite Conference Babelsberg [a district of Potsdam], Germany
> NO: WAR 41011
>
> To the President from the Secretary of War
>
> The time schedule on Groves' project is pro-
> gressing so rapidly that it is now essential that
> statement for release by you be available not later
> than Wednesday, 1 August.  I have revised draft of
> statement, which I previously presented to you, in
> light of
>
> (A) Your recent ultimatum,
> (B) Dramatic results of test and
> (C) Certain minor suggestions made by British
> of which Byrnes is aware.
>
> While I am planning to start a copy by special
> courier tomrrow in the hope you can be reached,
> nevertheless  in the event he does not reach you in
> time, I will appreciate having your authority to
> have White House release revised statement as soon as
> necessary.
>
> Sorry circumstances seem to require this emer-
> gency action.
>
> ACTION: Gen. Vaughan

And on the back side is Truman's hand written response:
[image]

> Sec War
>
> Reply to your 41011
> suggestions approved
> Release when ready
> but not sooner than
> August 2.
>
> HST

In reference to some comments, I'll add this concerning the meaning of this document, from a link by JMS (emphasis mine):

> Featured document in this section of the exhibit:
> Secretary of War to Harry S. Truman, July 30, 1945, with Truman's
> handwritten note on reverse. **No known written record exists** in which
> Harry Truman explicitly ordered the use of atomic weapons against
> Japan. **The closest thing to such a document is this handwritten order**,
> addressed to Secretary of War Henry Stimson, in which Truman
> authorized the release of a public statement about the use of the
> bomb. It was written on July 31, 1945 while Truman was attending the
> Potsdam Conference in Germany. **In effect, this served as final
> authorization for the employment of the atomic bomb,** though the
> expression “release when ready” refers to the public statement.

Comment: While interesting, this does not seem to answer any of the questions of OP. *That* Truman authorized the bomb is clear, but wasn't part of it... can you elaborate?

Comment: The answer below suggests "release when ready" refers to a press statement to be released, not the bomb being released over Japan.

Comment: @Richard There's much more than suggestion. Look at the memo: the writer says "it is essential that statement for release by you be available not later than Wednesday, 1 August" and discusses editing the statement. Then, "I will appreciate having your authority to have White House release revised statement as soon as necessary." Truman replies "Suggestions approved. Release when ready but not sooner than August 2." It is absolutely clear that this refers to the statement.

Comment: I know I'm usually "the short answer guy", but I'd like a little more meat as well. For instance, how does the date on this correspond to the date it was carried out? What happened in the meantime?

Comment: @justCal - That's a shame. I hope you get better and/or find a solution (voice rec is starting to get pretty good these days).

Comment: I agree with @walen. It'd be really nice if you can transcribe it. The scan is really hard to read with my eyes. It seems quite interesting though! (I should say that handwritten document is fine but then again maybe younger people don't know how to read it? But the others absolutely a transcription would be welcome from me.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby the "statement" could certainly be an order, not a public statement. If it's about a public statement, where is it? It should be public, shouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84840/discussion-between-david-richerby-and-de-novo).

Answer (score 18):

**Important Dates:**

- **April 1939** - **[Germany begins developing their atomic bomb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_nuclear_weapons_program)**.
- **August 2, 1939** - **[Albert Einstein sends a letter written by Leo Szilard to Franklin Roosevelt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Szil%C3%A1rd_letter)**, warnings of an atom bomb being developed by NAZI Germany and recommending America needed its own atomic program.  Effectively starting the US nuclear program.
- **August 19, 1943** - Churchill and Franklin Roosevelt agree on the Quebec Agreement, **[outlining the terms for the coordinated development of the science and engineering related to nuclear energy, and, specifically nuclear weapons.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_Agreement)**
- **March 25, 1945** - **[Albert Einstein Writes again to Roosevelt](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/bomb/large/documents/index.php?documentdate=1945-03-25&documentid=3-5&pagenumber=1)** to say the scientists working on the bomb need more contact with the decision makers who will decide to use the bomb.
- **April 12, 1945** - President Franklin Delano Roosevelt Dies.
- **April 24, 1945** - Sec Defense **[Henry Stimson schedules a meeting with President Harry Truman](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/bomb/large/documents/index.php?documentdate=1945-04-24&documentid=9-14&pagenumber=1)** to tell him about the Bomb.
- **May 9, 1945** - Truman establishes the **[Interim Committee](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/bomb/large/documents/index.php?documentid=35&pagenumber=1)** to recommend temporary wartime controls on how to handle the bomb.
- **May 12, 1945** - **[Second meeting of the Targeting Committee](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/bomb/large/documents/index.php?documentid=29&pagenumber=1)**, and first mentioning of Hiroshima as a target.
- **July 17th - August 2, 1945** - The Potsdam Conference Meets.
- **July 27th 1945** - **[Potsdam Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potsdam_Declaration)** is made to Japan calling for the surrender of all Japanese forces by the allies, the declaration lays out the conditions.  Doesn't mention the bomb but says unless Japan surrenders it faces "prompt and utter destruction".  Japan does not respond and the allies( US and Britain) take this as a rejection.  Soviet Union is not part of the decision as it is still neutral in the Pacific War.
- **July 30, 1945** - Secretary of War to Harry S. Truman, with Truman's handwritten note on reverse.  Truman hand writes approval for press release upon dropping the bomb. This effectively is the Presidents final approval to drop two atomic bombs on imperial Japan.
- **Aug 6, 1945**  -  The Enola Gay drops the first Bomb on Hiroshima.
- **Aug 6, 1945**  -  President Truman on **[board the USS Augusta](https://www.c-span.org/video/?294914-1/president-truman-speech-bombing-hiroshima)** in the mid-Atlantic returning to the United States from the Potsdam Conference" when he was informed that the bomb had been dropped.
- **Aug 8th, 1945** - Soviet Union declares war on Japan.
- **Aug 9, 1945** -  The [Bockscar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bockscar) drops the second bomb on Nagasaki.
- **Aug 15, 1945** - Japan Announces Surrender.

> **Question:**
>   Am I correct in assuming that Truman and only Truman had the authority to order the bombing of Hiroshima? After all, it was the very first A-bomb and procedures may not have been formalized yet. It occurs to me that maybe a theater commander like Gen. MacArthur could have given the order.

Yes Truman made the decision to drop the first two Atomic bombs on Hiroshima August 6th 1945, and Nagasaki August 9th 1945.  Truman also approved the targets both of which were recommended by a presidential committee called the Interim Committee made up of Presidential cabinet advisors.

Within Days of being told of the bomb's details he established the Interim Committee made up of Cabinet Officials.  The Interim Committee created a military advisory group as well as a scientific advisory group and these men recommended the targets for the bomb as well as recommended the logistics.

The Interim Committee had both scientific advisors and military advisors in selecting the targets, which Truman approved.

> **Question:**
>   Given that Truman was at Potsdam when he made the decision to bomb Hiroshima, did he have a secure method of communications to use to communicate his order from Potsdam? If so, what was that method? When was that order actually given? I'm guessing it was at least several days before the bombing since someone had to order the bomb moved to Tinian and a plane and flight crew chosen and assembled at Tinian.

Truman had made the tentative decision to move forward with preparing to drop the bomb before Potsdam.

The Final Authorization was given July 31, 1945, by Truman at Potsdam.  Truman, Churchill, and the Interim Committee all communicated by way of Cables and secret courier.

> **[Truman Library](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/hst/d.htm)**
>   No known written record exists in which Harry Truman explicitly ordered the use of atomic weapons against Japan. [The closest thing to such a document is the handwritten order, addressed to Secretary of War Henry Stimson, in which Truman authorized the release of a public statement about the use of the bomb](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/exhibit_documents/index.php?tldate=1945-07-30&groupid=3452&pagenumber=1&collectionid=abomb). It was written on July 31, 1945 while Truman was attending the Potsdam Conference in Germany. In effect, this served as final authorization for the employment of the atomic bomb, though the expression “release when ready” refers to the public statement.

Comment: "*the scientists working on the bomb more contact with the decision makers*" clearly has some typo. My best guess is that it's missing the word *need* between *bomb* and *more*.

Comment: "Truman made the decision to drop the first two Atomic bombs on Hiroshima August 6th 1945, and Nagasaki August 9th 1945." That's an oversimplification to the point of not really being true. The Nagasaki raid was originally scheduled for August 11th but was brought forward because of anticipated bad weather. The primary target even then was Kokura but visibility was too bad so they went to the secondary. Truman made the decision to drop the bombs and approved the target lists and general timing, but most of the details were left to Col. Tibbets.

Comment: Actually it was due to poor visibility that Nagasaki was bombed; the original target was Kokura (although Kyoto was also at the top of the list but due to cultural reasons it was suggested to not attack); Nagasaki wasn't on the original list. Ah, and I see that @DavidRicherby covered some of that.

Comment: You could add this to your timeline: **August 10th, 1945**: Truman requires an explicit presidential order before any additional atomic strike, see [my answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/48915/33930)

Comment: @Pryftan Your comment could, I think, be misinterpreted. The original target list, drawn up in late May 1945 was Kokura, Hiroshima, Yokohama, Niigata and Kyoto. Kyoto was removed from the list because of its cultural importance and Nagasaki replaced it. However, on 6th August, Hiroshima was the primary target, with Kokura and Nagasaki as alternates; on 9th August, Kokura was the primary and Nagasaki the alternate. Kyoto wasn't a target of either bombing mission.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Perhaps so. But it could be - how to say it? - semantics too. Maybe it's better then to say that it was suggested but never was on the list literally because of the culture significance. In that case I would concede indeed.

Comment: @Pryftan Everything I've seen says that Kyoto _was_ on the original list, but was removed from it. No plane ever took off with a nuclear weapon and a target list that included Kyoto but there was definitely a time when there were plans to use the bomb there. (And -- pet peeve -- yes, this is exactly "semantics". Semantics is precisely "the meaning of language" and the whole point is that I think your words could be interpreted to have the wrong meaning.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know well what semantics means. I think you missed what I was trying to say perhaps because I was struggling to find the right way to say it (least of my issues - far far far worse for some time now). But yes. You're saying the same thing as I am hence me conceding with you.

Answer (score 8):

> Am I correct in assuming that Truman and only Truman had the authority to order the bombing of Hiroshima?

No

[According to historian William Johnston](http://www.courant.com/opinion/editorials/hc-op-hiroshima-truman-changed-story-about-bombings-20150804-story.html), at the time of the bombing, field commanders had the authority. Truman changed this the day after the second bomb was dropped (on Nagasaki), explicitly requiring a presidential order for any additional strike.

> President Truman's first explicit decision about the atomic bombs stopped their further use without his "express authority."
>
> Despite Truman's later claims, he never sat down with his advisers, listened to their arguments and made an explicit decision to use the bombs. More accurately, he condoned rather than decided the atomic bombings of Japan.

This source, its context, and further history over presidential vs. field commander control of atomic and nuclear strikes are discussed in [this smithsonian magazine article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/how-the-presidency-took-control-americas-nuclear-arsenal-180967747/), and [this October 3, 2017 radiolab episode](https://www.wnycstudios.org/story/nukes-broadcast).

#### Primary sources:

[Response from Chief of Staff Marshall to General Groves, 10th August 1945](https://nsarchive2.gwu.edu//NSAEBB/NSAEBB162/67.pdf):

> "It is not to be released on Japan without express authority from the President."

"It" refers to the third bomb, which Groves indicated would be ready for delivery on the target as early as August 17 1945.

[10th August 1945 diary entry by Henry Wallace](https://nsarchive2.gwu.edu//NSAEBB/NSAEBB162/65.pdf):

> Truman said he had given orders to stop atomic bombing. he said the thought of wiping out another 100,000 people was too horrible. He didn't like the idea of killing, as he said, "all those kids."

From these primary sources, Johnston's interpretation, that authority to order the release of an atomic bomb was in the field prior to August 10th 1945, seems reasonable.

Comment: May I politely request the use of unambiguous date formats to avoid confusion with SE's global userbase?   8/10 and 10/8 are confusing.  Either use yyyy-mm-dd as per ISO8601 or use full text like 8 October 1945.